# Google cloud messaging (GCM) with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to figure out about sending push notification using PHP.
The problem is, how to register **service worker** in browser and send notification directly from PHP.

I got sample of code for back-end part:

```
    <?php
        define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'SOME KEY' );
        $registrationIds = array('fK_LVMivilI:APA91bHCXawEoNXc0Avwk4F6iYsshn4mmWX6jysrg8gC9PGA6_AlqWtr1HXhIMonCCUj8syOlsDGTFJVu_T3aPqdMNynqy7SY5L9OBlgolu-7L2a5pwZrB7kN_bdnUPeZHJQ1HT2i2ed');
        $msg = array
        (
            'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
            'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
            'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
            'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
            'vibrate'   => 1,
            'sound'     => 1,
            'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
            'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
        );
        $fields = array
        (
            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
            'data'          => $msg
        );

        $headers = array
        (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        echo $result;
```

When I'm trying to run this script, I'm getting the following error:

```
{"multicast_id":7003820144951503575,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

I guess it's because there are no service workers registered in the browser.

So, I need some solution to send notification with dynamic content using PHP and javascript if needed.

Any advice appricated.

Comment: check your registration id. is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en) on how to register a Service Worker in implementing Push Messaging. It is stated here that there is a dependency of having a service worker to implement push messages for the web. The reason for this is that when a push message is received, the browser can start up a service worker, which runs in the background without a page being open, and dispatch an event so that you can decide how to handle that push message.

This is the sample code use for this.

```
var isPushEnabled = false;

…

window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
var pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-button'); 
pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() { 
if (isPushEnabled) { 
unsubscribe(); 
} else { 
subscribe(); 
} 
});

// Check that service workers are supported, if so, progressively 
// enhance and add push messaging support, otherwise continue without it. 
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { 
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js') 
.then(initialiseState); 
} else { 
console.warn('Service workers aren\'t supported in this browser.'); 
} 
});
```

For more information about Service Worker, check this tutorials:

- [PUSH NOTIFICATIONS ON THE WEB - GOOGLE CHROME](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/push-notifications-on-the-web---google-chrome/10128)
- [WEB PUSH NOTIFICATION WITH SERVICE WORKER](https://www.ajaxtown.com/article/web-push-notification-with-service-worker)
- [mybb-gcm-push-notifications/service-worker.js.php](https://github.com/marcandrews/mybb-gcm-push-notifications/blob/master/service-worker.js.php)

Comment: The main problem for me is to send data from my PHP back end and fill up service worker notification.